# Can I reconfigure postgrey to keep mail instead of rejecting it?

Tags: email, postfix

I have postgrey on my mailserver and it works really well. I actually suspect it works a little too well in that there are quite a lot of faulty mailservers out there that don't bother retrying.

Frequently I find people mail me, I can watch the mail hit my mailserver, get greylisted and rejected... and then the mail never gets redelivered. Clearly the sending mailserver is "broken" and needs fixing, but that's beyond my control and all I want is to read my email.

Can I make postgrey dump all rejected mail into a separate mailbox so I can go through it to look for "missing" mail? Or is the only solution to turn postgrey off and put up with the incessant stock spam?